# redirecionar página javascript depois de animação

Tags: javascript, html5, animação, redirecionamento

Boas, estou a fazer um jogo em HTML5 + CSS3 + JavaScript e estou na parte do menu inicial. Eu queria que o botão antes de redirecionar a página fizesse uma animação. A parte da animação está a funcionar bem, mas a partir do momento em que insiro a parte do código para redirecionar a página, deixa de executar a animação. Alguém sabe como ajudar? Em baixo deixo a parte do código em JavaScript.

```
function ajuda(){
this.style.backgroundPosition = "right";
var sombotao = document.getElementById("sombotao");
sombotao.play();            
window.location.href="ajuda.html";                
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o evento [`ended` do HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended_(Web_Audio)), a descrição é:

> ***O evento é disparado quando a reprodução tiver acabado por ter chegado ao fim***
>
> The ended event is fired when playback has stopped because the end of the media was reached.

Nesse caso poderia ser assim:

```
function ajuda() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "right";
    var sombotao = document.getElementById("sombotao");
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
         window.location.href = "ajuda.html";
    });
    sombotao.play();
}
```